# Collapsing margin on Flexbox children

Tags: css, margin, flexbox

I have the following arrangement via flexbox with flex-wrap and elements able to stretch using flex-grow:

[image: flexbox]

Each item has a margin on all sides. This is to separate the items from each other, but the side effect is the whole block has margins which I'd like to collapse. It could be done with rules like `nth-child(-n+3) { margin-top: 0; }` but because the container size could vary, there could be any number of items per row and any number of rows. So I'm wondering if flex-box has any way to collapse the outer margins in a setup like this, while retaining the margins between items.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/helav/1/edit?html,css,output)

The HTML is simply 6 items inside a container.

The CSS (Sass) is as follows:

```
.container
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  background: #eef
  align-items: stretch

.item
  flex-grow: 1  
  margin: 1em
  border: 1px solid black
  padding: 1em
  min-width: 6em
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can add a negative margin on the flex container to cancel out the items' margins along the edges, and then move its "background" styling to a parent wrapper-element.

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ziyopepivi/1)

Updated CSS (SASS):

```
.wrapper
  background: #eef
  border: 1px solid darkgray

.container
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  margin: -1em

.item
  flex-grow: 1  
  margin: 1em
  border: 1px solid black
  padding: 1em
  min-width: 6em
```

Comment: Seems like a wrapper might be the only solution for this, unless anyone can suggest a pure flexbox solution.

Comment: Worked for me.  Had to put container within another container, then add margin to the outermost container due to the container eating away whatever margin was on the outside that wasn't added by each flexbox element.  Good solution though, definitely using it.

Answer (score 0):

Another hack is to *split the margin responsibilities* between container and item, **each caring about half** (say `$margin` is `1em`):

• **container** cares about its *bottom margin* and *half left + half-right* of items:

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;           // Go to next line if not enough space
   padding-top: 0;            // Let items handle top
   padding-left: $margin/2;   // Handle half of left
   padding-bottom: $margin;   // Handle bottom
   padding-right: $margin/2;  // Handle half of right
}
```

• **items** care about *top* and *half left + half right*:

```
.item {
   flex-grow: 1;             // Use available space
   margin-left: $margin/2;   // Handle other half of left
   margin-right: $margin/2;  // Handle other half of right
   margin-top: $margin;      // Handle top
}
```

Regarding items size, you can set a `width` if you want items to look the same.

```
.item.fixed {
   width: 15em;
}
```

See a [demo here](https://codepen.io/Javarome/pen/xxZdgdr).